# Tensorflow passing image to simple MNIST Data Model

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I have simple model for MNIST data classification with accuracy around 92%.

I would like to know if there is any way I can provide image with digit and get label as output for that digit ? Image can be from mnist test data, rather than custom  image, just to avoid image preprocessing? Below is code for my model.

Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf

#reset graph
tf.reset_default_graph()

#constants
learning_rate = 0.5
batch_size = 100
training_epochs = 5
logs_path = "/tmp/mnist/2"

#load mnist data set
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,784], name = "image-input")
    y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name = "labels-input")
#weights
with tf.name_scope("weights"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
#biases
with tf.name_scope("biases"):
    b=  tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

#Activation function softmax
with tf.name_scope("softmax"):
    #y is prediction
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) +b)

#Cost function
with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1])) #????

#Define Optimizer
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

#Accuracy
with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))

tf.summary.scalar("cost",cross_entropy)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy",accuracy)
#Merge all summaries into a single "operation" which will be executed in a session
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #initialize variables before using them
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #log writer object
   # writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path,graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    #training cycles
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #number of batches in one epoch
        batch_count = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        for i in range(batch_count):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _,summary = sess.run([train_optimizer,summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_:batch_y})
            writer.add_summary(summary,epoch * batch_count + i)
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            print("Epoch: ",epoch)
    print("Accuracy: ",accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels}))
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 2):

After you trained the network, you can get the label that the network gives to a new image by doing

```
new_image_label= sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: new_image})
```

Note that the format of `new_image` should be the same as of `batch_x`. Think about `new_image` as a batch of size 1, so if `batch_x` is 2D, `new_image` should also be 2D (of shape 1 by 784).

In addition, if you did some pre-processing (like normalization for example) to the images in `batch_x`, you need to do the same thing with `new_image`.

You could also get the labels of several images simultaneously with the same code as above. Just replace `new_image` with some 2D array of several images `new_images`.

Comment: So just below my code I should add that line of code from your answer, where new_image will be path to the image which I want to test and which has to have same size as images in batch_x ?

Comment: Yes, just add it inside the "with tf.Session() as sess:", after the loop (for epoch in range(training_epochs)) ends